# .Net 5 environment variables priority order

Tags: environment-variables, .net-5

To deploy my application it's necessary to change the variable ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT to production but .net seems to read the variable from launchsettings.json instead of read the system variable.

**Is this behavior correct?**

**What'd be the best to set this variable?**

Obs1: if I delete the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENTfrom launchsettings.json, it reads the value from system

Obs2: I'm trying to deploy to heroku using the config vars to set the ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT but it also doesn't work on my machine(Linux).

Comment: I think launchsettings.json is just for running locally with Visual Studio. Could you try appsettings.json?